# BITRIX Экспорт в CSV: в IP_PROP вместо NAME сохраняет ID

Tags: php, битрикс, csv, export

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь сделать выгрузку CSV товаров с сайта на Bitrix. Использую стандартный компонент **Контент->Инфоблоки->ЭкспортCSV** .

Создаю новую выгрузку, отмечаю необходимое и обязательное **Название (B_IBLOCK_ELEMENT.NAME)**.

Среди параметров также отмечаю поле, которое содержит тестовое имя "Фабрика", ну соответственно выгружаться должно название фабрики. Но выгружается ID этой фабрики.

Думаю, что копать надо в сторону `/bitrix/modules/catalog/load/csv_new_run.php`
Но не совсем понимаю, что конкретно здесь надо изменить, чтобы в выводилось **Имя** вместо **ID**

И ещё момент, возможно, это тоже важно:
Фабрики, по всей видимости отдельная таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это поле какого типа? Если "привязка к элементу", то все правильно, штатный функционал забирает только id записи к которой идет привязка.

Comment: @NikolajSarry да, именно привязка к элементу. А есть возможность это обойти? Если да, было бы очень хорошо, если с примером, а то в этом csv_new_run мозг сломаешь)

Comment: к сожалению тут только три варианта: 1 - писать свой экспорт, 2 - модифицировать тот что у битрикса, 3 - искать в маркетплэйсе решение удовлетворяющее требованию. Но если вы сделаете экспорт основого инфоблока и того к которому привязка, а затем их в правильной последовательности импортируете, то должно все привязаться по новой. Но не факт. А не пробовали экспорт в xml.

Comment: @NikolajSarry Да тут весь прикол в том, что заказчика устраивает только CSV. Можно, конечно, сделать на php конвертер из YML в CSV, но довольно муторно рисовать все эти param name из XMLки.